# Which phrase is correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

"I happened upon this video" or 
"I happened on this video" I read the latter in a blog post, but I've heard the former mostly. Which is right?

Comment: Did you try looking it up in the dictionary? The [definitions of happen](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/happen+upon) often include something like `to meet or discover by chance (usually followed by on or upon)` and Oxford's lists "upon" as a synonym for "on", although more formal in tone.

Comment: simply... 'upon' - correct though formal. 'on' - snappy & modern, by comparison. 'on' may be grammatically less sure of itself, but the meaning to the native reader is implicit.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I don't think just switching from ***upon*** to ***on*** is enough to make such a dated/formal usage sound "snappy & modern".

Comment: Agreed, @FumbleFingers - I dropped a comment on one post, just "I found..." which works just fine for me, no hark-back to Defoe/Dickens... [I did caveat with 'by comparison' but agree it isn't exactly 21st Century]

Comment: I don't understand the closevotes, and have voted to reopen. After a quick check of online dictionaries, I can't find anything pointing out that ***upon*** is (was) far more common than ***on***. Nor is there anything to tell you that ["come across" is much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+happened+upon+a%2Che+came+across+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20happened%20upon%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20came%20across%20a%3B%2Cc0). These are relevant things for learners to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You risk sounding dated/stilted/starchy/formal if you use the phrasal verb ***happen upon*** (or more often, ***chance upon***) in many spoken contexts today.

Here's [a chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20happened%20upon%2Che%20chanced%20upon%2Che%20happened%20on%2Che%20chanced%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20happened%20upon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20chanced%20upon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20happened%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20chanced%20on%3B%2Cc0) showing that ***upon*** is far more common than ***on***, and [here's another one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happened%20upon%20it%2Cchanced%20upon%20it%2Ccame%20across%20it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chappened%20upon%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchanced%20upon%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccame%20across%20it%3B%2Cc0) showing that the for the past century and a half, by far the more common phrasing is...

> **come across** ([phrasal verbs: defn 2.1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/come)) *- meet or find by chance*

Answer (score 0):

Some people say them both but you could best write it as: "I happened to discover this video".

Comment: ... or just 'I found...'